# How can i tell which form loads first?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a program that has 2 forms (FormLogin, FormMain). When I try to debug I nothing happens and I think it's attempting to go to the incorrect Form. Is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

Comment: Which form is set to be the startup form in your project? Right Click on Project goto  properties --> apppliction --> Stertup Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the `Project` menu, at the bottom click `YourProject Properties...`
On the `Application` tab you will see an entry called `Startup Form`. From the dropdown you can pick which form is the starting object.

This information is stored in the My Project folder, Application.Designer.vb and Application.myapp files but you should just use the GUI to change the startup form unless you have a good reason to edit the auto generated files directly.